# A word for a military unit still functioning?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which is the antonym for a military unit being destroyed or degraded. I considered **live**, but that has the connotation of a single being. I considered **active**,  but my phrasing should be useful even if the unit is, say, encamped and not currently doing anything. What would the term-of-art be here?

> Reports that the military unit were scattered and destroyed turned out
>   to be in error; rather, the unit was still ____.

Comment: Do you mean the unit STILL EXISTS: ie "has *not* been **disbanded by the government** and is no longer in existence".  For example: **"the Black Watch is disbanded, it no longer exists (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Watch), whereas the Scots Guards are still in existence."**  Is that what you mean?  **OR** is what you mean **"At 3PM during the battle, we thought the Highland Brigade had been scattered and reduced to ineffectiveness, but in fact, they were still fighting cohesively as one unit."**  Which do you mean?  They are totally different. Your explanation and example are at odds.

Comment: (news link http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/4190805/Black-Watch-and-Royal-Scots-are-among-ten-regiments-to-be-axed-in-cull-of-Army.html )

Comment: @JoeBlow: More in the "still exists" sense; "able to fight".

Comment: I don't understand (sorry).  Looking at my long comment there, do you mean the former or the latter.  Cheers

Comment: Don't have time for a full answer, but "unbroken" perhaps. As an antonym to broken in the sense of scattered and without morale.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The adjective [**operational**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/operational) comes to mind which means:

> Relating to active operations of the armed forces, police, or
>   emergency services

Your example:

> Reports that the military unit **was** scattered and destroyed turned
>   out to be in error; rather, the unit was still (tactically)
>   **operational**.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: I was typing that!

Comment: @NVZ Sorry, I worked as a typist in the army.  :-)

Comment: @Rathony - Seems like this question was tailored for you then! ;)

Comment: This overlaps with the common noun form **operational readiness** or simply **readiness**.  These terms are [frequently used](https://www.google.com/search?q=military+readiness+gao) by the Government Accounting Office.

Comment: Or maybe the similar "[**operative**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/operative)".

Comment: (Even though I recognize this answer was accepted,) OP writes: "My phrasing should be useful even if the unit is, say, encamped and not currently doing anything."  While "operational" may be technically accurate in referring to a unit in such a state, and encampment is part of many missions, common usage of the term implies that the operational unit is actively engaged in pursuit of a specific objective, excluding units that are "not currently doing anything."

Comment: As I said, "operational" may be a technically correct term for an encamped unit, but when trying to communicate with a lay audience it may not be the best choice of word to convey everything the OP is attempting to convey, especially for the "not doing anything" case.  "Operational" carries a strong connotation of doing *something,* and we could debate about whether or not being encamped and ready for action counts as doing something (it certainly requires a good amount of effort and resources), but OP specifically asked about "not doing anything," which "operational" doesn't seem to cover.

Comment: @Rathony it doesn't matter exactly what activities the OP meant by "doing nothing."  My point is that the connotations of the word "operational" *excludes* the concept of "doing nothing," *whatever you consider "nothing" to be,* and thus "operational" may not be the best answer for the question, even if it does address part of the question and was posted and accepted quickly.

Comment: @Rathony the comment only applies to the answer "operational" (or possibly other operati-* words).  Imagine the following snippet: "I know the damage is bad, but what's left?" "We've got three units operational and two on standby." I think OP is looking for one word that could apply equally to all five units and not to any units that were destroyed or degraded.  In common usage, "operational" excludes the second concept OP seems to be seeking to cover.

Answer (score 21):

From many books I've read that cover this genre I would go with ***combat effective***.

[Combat effectiveness](http://www.britannica.com/topic/combat-effectiveness) - the readiness of a military unit to engage in combat based on behavioral, operational, and leadership considerations. Combat effectiveness measures the ability of a military force to accomplish its objective and is one component of overall military effectiveness.

Comment: Would "combat ready" not pertain more to this case?

Comment: That's certainly a good answer however, I feel as if combat effective gives it more of a cold military impression. Would be interesting to know what context it will be used in.

Comment: Agreed; combat effective/combat ineffective is an actual phrase used in the military to assess a given unit's ability to complete a mission/do it's job.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - Except combat effective is the actual military term, even though it's being used to describe a state of readiness. A field officer would report to his superiors that his unit is _combat effective_, or tests would be done to determine if a unit is _combat effective_ before deploying that force.

Answer (score 10):

I think the word you're looking for is "...active."

Answer (score 5):

It's probably more appropriate for the navy, or equipment rather than entire units, but there is ***in commission***.

> [**in commission**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commission) -  in use or in condition for use

On the flip side, a still cohesive unit that has been withdrawn to regroup is *out of commission*; they can not be recommitted until necessary reconfiguration has been done.

Comment: "In commission", while a valid phrase, is more about the administrative status of the unit, rather than the tactical readiness. You wouldn't describe a defeated unit as "decommissioned", for example.

Comment: Jon - OP is indeed asking, specifically, about "administrative existence", not actual readiness, condition etc.  *"but my phrasing should be useful even if the unit is, say, encamped and not currently doing anything*"

Comment: That being said, the OPs example in a quote box, completely contradicts that.  oh well.

Comment: @JonStory - "out of commission" was mentioned in my answer.  It's not synonymous with *decommissioned*.

Comment: No, but either does it relate to tactical readiness, which is what this question asks for. I can see where you came from with the answer, but it has a slightly different meaning to my eyes and I think it's worth pointing out: whether the asker cares about that difference is then up to them

Comment: @JonStory - I know, and I don't mind the comment.  It's just that I did not suggest the word *commissioned*, but the phrase *in commission*.  *Decommissioned* is the antonym of the former, which has a meaning more along the lines of *authorized* rather than "in service."

Comment: While I accept there's a slight difference, I'd still argue that "in commission" is as close to "commissioned" as to be virtually synonymous unless someone is very familiar with the domain, and potentially even if they are.

Answer (score 3):

"Fully Mission Capable," is the phrase that we used in the US Army to describe everything from large groups of military personnel being able to carry out a mission, the ability of a vehicle to continue combat/logistics operations, or a radio's ability to receive/transmit consistently.

Comment: As a technical term used by the military itself, this answer seems underrated to me.

Answer (score 2):

> Reports that the military unit were scattered and destroyed turned out to be in error; rather, the unit was still ***[viable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/viable)***.

a :  capable of working, functioning, or developing adequately (*viable* alternatives)
b :  capable of existence and development as an independent unit (the colony is now a *viable* state)
c (1) :  having a reasonable chance of succeeding (a *viable* candidate)
c (2) :  financially sustainable (a *viable* enterprise)

Answer (score 2):

If it has not been destroyed or degraded it is intact.

Answer (score 1):

Not a single word but how about ***fighting fit***?

The [Glossary of Military Terms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_military_slang) indicates that this phrase is used by the British and Indian Armies. And it is idiomatic too.

> Reports that the military *units* were scattered and destroyed turned out to be in error; rather, the *units were* still ***fighting fit***.

Comment: It may be be techniczlly correct for me to say this, but "fighting fit" implies a unit near peak performance, while merely "operational" can include this and a unit that's suffered but not so much as to be out of of comission.

Comment: @ChrisH - I concur. Since Rathony had already posted "operational" as an answer, I suggested this. Naturally, "operational" has been up-voted many times and probably works best for OP's context. But I reckon there's nothing wrong for the general English enthusiasts who get to read more answers.

Comment: I thought it was something like that -- I (too-) often comment a caveat on word-choice answers that I think are good but not the best fit.

Answer (score 1):

*Extant* emphasizes more that the soldiers were not all killed. *Cohesive* emphasizes more that they are not scattered. Either of these fit fine in your original sentence:

---

**Extant**

adjective

1. in existence; still existing; not destroyed or lost

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extant?s=t

> Reports that the military unit were scattered and destroyed turned out
> to be in error; rather, the unit was still *extant*.

---

---

**Cohesive**

adjective

1. characterized by or causing the state of (cohering, uniting, or sticking together.)

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cohesive?s=t

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cohesion

> Reports that the military unit were scattered and destroyed turned out
> to be in error; rather, the unit was still *cohesive*.

Answer (score 0):

*Reports that the military unit were scattered and destroyed turned out to be in error; rather, the unit was still **in one piece***.

> in one piece: not injured or damaged. Etymology: based on the idea of an object that is not broken [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+one+piece)

Comment: Actually this is probably the best answer, to describe *remaining cohesive and operational*.

Comment: In one piece would imply that there have been no casualties. A unit can still be operational and combat effective after some casualties.

Answer (score 0):

How about steady?

I'm pretty sure I've seen that as a status in wargaming rules (along with shaken, disordered, impetuous etc.)

Comment: Please explain how it is used. Remember, you're answering for people who don't already know the answer.

Answer (score -1):

How about functional. Scattered and destroyed can not be functional and that which can not be something must be its opposite - it's antonym